# Concatenating value to a command line

Tags: vb.net

I am making a program that uses the rasidal command to connect to a VPN server. Obviously this requires a login and this is stored in a notepad file.

```
Process.Start("rasdial.exe", """VPN Connection"" HardcodedUSERNAME HardCodedPassword")
```

This seems to work fine, however when I read this information from a notepad file and write it to the screen they are still exactly the same. Why is it that the login could be incorrect.

All I am doing is

```
Process.Start("rasdial.exe", """VPN Connection"" & Info")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "info" is never used. Try it out an remove the info-variable or rename it.

Do you have to double-quote "VPN Connection"? So try this one:

```
Process.Start("rasdial.exe", """VPN Connection"" " & Info)
```

And can you please tell me what your info-variable contains.

Comment: The user name and password.

Comment: Dim Reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(LoginFIlePath)
        Dim COntent As New RichTextBox
        COntent.Text = Reader.ReadToEnd
        Reader.Close()

        For Each Line As String In COntent.Lines
            If Username = "" Then
                Username = Line
            Else
                Password = Line
            End If

        Next
        Dim info As String
        info = Username + Password
        Console.WriteLine(info)

Comment: It reads the information from a notpad file (That works fine) then saves each line as the pass/username and then I save that as one variable "info". I then try and use that in the rasdial thing....